# Use fts(3) functions to rename files and directories. only first level gets changed

Tags: linux, c

it's just a simple prog to replace spaces with underscores. i found a bash script that will do it but it's slow. from what i understand i want a depth-first search and i want my remove_space function to be called on directories in postorder (on the way back up). do i understand the terminology correctly? how it is now i have to call the program as many times as there are dir levels for it to change all the names. i think because it changes dir names in preorder when it goes back to enter the dir it can't find it because it's looking for the old name. do you know how i can call my function on directories in postoder?

thanks in advance!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char * const *old_name = (argv + 1);
int opts = 0;
FTS *ftsp;
FTSENT *scan;

if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <dir path>\n", *argv);
    exit(1);
}

opts |= (FTS_PHYSICAL | FTS_SEEDOT | FTS_XDEV);

ftsp = fts_open(old_name, opts, NULL);

while ((scan = fts_read(ftsp)) != NULL) {
    if (scan->fts_info == FTS_DOT)
        continue;
    remove_space(scan->fts_name);
    printf("%s\n", scan->fts_name);
}

fts_close(ftsp);
return 0;
}

int remove_space(const char *old_str) {
char new_str[strlen(old_str)];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (*(old_str + i)) {
    if (isalnum(*(old_str + i))) {
        while (*(old_str + i)) {

            if (*(old_str + i) == SPACE)
                *(new_str + j) = UNDER_SCORE;
            else
                *(new_str + j) = *(old_str  + i);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
*(new_str + j) = '\0';
rename(old_str, new_str);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the man page says, on *fts_read*:

> Directories (that are readable and do  not  cause cycles) are visited
>   at least twice, once in preorder and once in postorder.

So one way to do it consist to test if this is a directory and skip it when it's your first encounter of it.

An other way is described in the man page, on *fts_set*, with options FTS_AGAIN:

> Normal use is for postorder directory visits, where it causes the 
>   directory to  be  revisited (in both preorder and postorder) as well
>   as all of its descendants.

BTW, if performance is your problem, you may use *fts_children*, with **FTS_NAMEONLY** options

Comment: helpful Coren. Thank you

Comment: Also, checking for FTS_DP makes sure i only edit the directory in postorder. That made a bid difference for my implementaion.